# Найдите прямые(,) параллельные BD

Tags: запятые

Запятая не нужна?

> Найдите прямые(,) параллельные BD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно с запятой и только с запятой:

***Найдите прямы́е, параллéльные BD***.

Два ударения, подчëркивается именно признак. Смысловым центром сделать это нельзя. Даже если без потери смысла опустить нельзя, запятую тяжело не поставить. В любом случае она нужна.

Comment: Ну а на фиг правило Розенталя тогда? Когда оно-то применяется?